# Centering Sections in Body

Tags: html, css

I have a html with the following format

```
   <body>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   </body>
```

The body is the entire page, I want each section to be horizontally centered in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are centered by default (with 100% width). If you specify a width < 100%, use a left/right margin of `auto` to center them horizontally.

```css
body {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1em;
}

section {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
</body>
```

You can also use `display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;` on the parent to center the sections horizontally.

```css
body {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1em;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}

section {
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
</body>
```